# Persistent iFrame in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Does anyone happen to know if it is possible to have a persistent iFrame in a Chrome Extension? Currently I have the iFrame running in the background page, but I would like to be able to have it visible to the user (it is a video player so even though video is playing, the user has not way of clicking the controls). The goal is that if the user closes the popup of the extension the video still players and that when they click the popup again the video is still playing and they have access to the controls. It appears that this used to be possible with importNode / adoptNode in the past but it looks like these have been removed from the API.

Any help would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: You may want to take a look at the background page for the following extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keep-awake/bijihlabcfdnabacffofojgmehjdielb

It keeps ChromeOS from entering sleep mode. It may possibly run persistently in the background, though I'm not sure.

Comment: I pretty sure that if you use the show / hide the video is continue playing until you make it stop().Also you are able remove the controls from the player and set them back when you want to

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible with iframes - it sounds like the spec [was changed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Jun/0228.html) to make iframes reload whenever they are moved using adoptNode.

I see two less-than-ideal options for this case:

1. Use content scripts to keep track of the place in the video, and whenever the iframe with the video gets moved between the browser action popup and the background page and gets reloaded, you then seek the video to the location it was just at. This isn't the greatest user experience since there will be a hiccup.
2. Instead of having the video playing in the background page and trying to move it back and forth between that and a browser action popup, instead always just load the video in regular popup window. You can create a [type=popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-CreateType) window using chrome.windows.create, and then minimize/restore it by using chrome.windows.update to toggle between the [minimized and normal states](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-WindowState), perhaps minimizing it automatically whenever it [loses focus](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged). This isn't the greatest user experience because there will always be a minimized window that isn't as "hidden" from the user's window management system as it would be when having the video in the extension's background page.